# I am trying to take input from html form and save it to mySql using JDBC,AngularJS

Tags: java, mysql, angularjs

Here I am taking input from html form and save it to mySql using using JDBC connector. Also I am not sure, how I will save the date

> Error 1: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near  VALUES('a','a@b.com','abcd','2015-10-30')' at line 1
>
> Error 2: restaurant.my.exceptions.AppException: Error in adding
>   customer to the database

This is my DAO class:

```
public Customer addPerson(Customer customer) throws AppException {


    //jdbc resource
    Connection con = DBUtil.connectToDB();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs=null;


    try {
            //getting info from front end and setting it into database
            ps =con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO customer(First_Last_Name, EMAIL, PASSWORD, DATE_RESERVATION), VALUES(?,?,?,?)", PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            ps.setString(1,customer.getFull_Name());
            ps.setString(2,customer.getEmail());
            ps.setString(3,customer.getPassword());
            //ps.setString(4,customer.getFull_Name());

            java.util.Date utilDate=customer.getDate_Reservation();
            //@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
            ps.setDate(4,sqlDate);

//              
//          double uDate=new java.util.Date();
//          uDate=customer.getDate_Reservation();
//          java.sql.Date sDate = convertUtilToSql(uDate);
//          DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY - hh:mm:ss");
//          ps.setDate(4,df.format(uDate));
            ps.executeUpdate();
            //geting generated key
            rs= ps.getGeneratedKeys();

            if(rs.next()){
                customer.setId(rs.getInt(1));

            }

            return customer;    


    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new AppException("Error in adding customer to the database", e.getCause());
    }finally{
        DBUtil.closeResources(ps, rs, con);
    }



}
```

This is my Controller:

```
@POST
@Path("/add")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public AppResponse addCustomer(Customer customer){


    AppResponse resp = new AppResponse();
    // generating the common msg for successful/ unsuccessful connection
    try {
        //if successful show list
        CustomerDAO customerDAO=new CustomerDAO();
        customer=customerDAO.addPerson(customer);

        resp.setMessage("Customer has been added to the system");
        resp.setPayload(customer);

    } catch (AppException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        resp.setStatus(AppResponse.ERROR);
        resp.setMessage(e.getMessage());
    }

    //customerDAO.getAll();
    return resp;


}
```

This is my AngularJS code:

```
mctrl.addCustomer= function(){                          
        $http({                 
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'api/customer/add',
                data: mctrl.newCustomer
            }).success(function(data){
                console.log(data);
                mctrl.newCustomer=null;
            }).error(function(error){           
                console.log(error);                         
            });
        };
```

Comment: Can you kindly explain what is the issue you are facing ? The error you have posted means you have issues with your query and MYSQL is complaining about it. If you try to take the same query and run manually in MYSQL editor you may find the exact cause.

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you Amit.  The error was coming because of just a comma before VALUES in sql query. Thank you so much.